# Check and get the text after "near " in php

Tags: php

When someone writes:

"Near Tokyo"

I would like to check first if the $search contains "near" and if it does then take the "Tokyo" into a variable $location.

I tried this:

```
if(strpos($search, 'near') == true){
    $search = explode("near ", $location);
    echo $location;
    exit();
}
```

did not work, it does not execute the if statement

Comment: It does, it just evaluates to false. Try learning to debug. You're evaluating something to true, but is the output true with your input? Simply putting `echo strpos($search, 'near')` would've made you see your mistake.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have multiple bugs here:

- `strpos` may return 0, which signifies a match but will not compare equal to `true`
- `strpos` is case-sensitive, which would make your example not work (look into `stripos` instead)
- `explode` is also case-sensitive

It would probably be easiest to use a regex for this:

```
$input = "Near Tokyo";
if (preg_match('/near\s+(\w+)/i', $input, $matches)) {
    echo "Near: ".$matches[1]."\n";
}
else {
    echo "No match.\n";
}
```

**[See it in action](http://ideone.com/CDuue)**.

This particular regex will only match the next *word* after "near", but this can be modified to suit your requirements.

Answer (score 1):

returntype of `strpos` is int, not bool

http://php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php

so use (according to manual pages) this:

```
if(strpos($search, 'near') !== false)
```

Answer (score 0):

change it to:

```
if(strpos($search, 'near') !== false){
    $search = explode("near ", $location);
    echo $location;
    exit();
}
```

just take a look at the [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strrpos.php) where this behaviour is explained:

> It is easy to mistake the return values for "character found at
>   position 0" and "character not found". Here's how to detect the
>   difference:
>
> ```
> <?php
>
> $pos = strrpos($mystring, "b");
> if ($pos === false) { // note: three equal signs
>     // not found...
> }
>
> ?>
> ```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, [`strpos`](http://php.net/strpos), cumbersome boolean result handling. You probably should or should want to use [`stristr`](http://php.net/stristr) instead, which is also *case-insensitive*:

```
if (stristr($search, "Near")) {
```

And since you are extracting text anyway, why not use a regex? (People are using the awful explode workaround way too often.)

```
if (preg_match("'Near (\S+)'i", $search, $match)) {
    echo $match[1];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

use this to get a result:

```
if(strpos($search, 'near') !== false){
  $location = explode("near ", $search);
  print_r($location);
  exit();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$search = "Near Tokyo";

if(strpos($search, 'Near') === 0){
    $location = explode("Near ", $search);
    echo $location[1];
    exit();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

$search = "Near Tokoyo";
if(preg_match("/near ([a-z]+)/i", $search, $match))
{
    $location = $match[1];
    echo $location;
}

?>
```

EDIT:

Fixed some bugs in your code.

```
if(stripos($search, 'near') !== false){
    $location = explode("near ", $search);
    echo $location[0];
    exit();
}
```